# Why isn't the string.length updating?

Tags: javascript, string-length, nodelist

This is my first piece of code js done on my own. I am trying to have an input field to add items to the list and then if you press the button to generate code it will collect all the checked items and copy the text into another div.

Basically, my question is around two variables:

```
const list = listUl.children;
const listCopy = listUl.querySelectorAll('span');
```

Let say I have 4 items in the list. If I add a new item to the list I can see the `list.length` add this new item, it changes from 4 to 5.
But it doesn't happen with `listCopy.length` the value keeps being 4.

Why is it happening if `lstCopy` is inside of list?
How can I have `listCopy` updated too?

Here is my code:

```js
const addItemInput = document.querySelector('.addItemInput');
const addItemButton = document.querySelector('.addItemButton');
const copyText = document.querySelector('.generateCode');
const listUl = document.querySelector('.list');
const list = listUl.children;
const listCopy = listUl.querySelectorAll('span');
const clonedCode = document.querySelector('.code p');

//FUNCTION: Generate value/items = Draggable, Checkbox, Remove button
const attachItemListButton = (item) => {

    //Draggable
    item.draggable = "true";
    item.classList.add("list--item");

    //Checkbox
    let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.className = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.name = "chkboxName1";
    checkbox.value = "value";
    checkbox.id = "id";
    item.insertBefore(checkbox, item.childNodes[0] || null);

    //Remove button
    let remove = document.createElement('button');
    remove.className = 'remove';
    remove.textContent = 'x';
    item.appendChild(remove);
};
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    attachItemListButton(list[i]);
}


//Cloning code if there are checked items
copyText.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let copyTextFromList = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < listCopy.length; i += 1) {
    if (listCopy[i].parentNode.querySelector("input:checked")) {
      copyTextFromList += listCopy[i].textContent + ',';
    }
  }
  clonedCode.innerHTML = copyTextFromList;
});


//Add item from the input field to the list
addItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = addItemInput.value;
  listUl.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(span);
  attachItemListButton(li);
  addItemInput.value = '';
});


//FUNCTION: Remove button
listUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
        if (event.target.className == 'remove') {
            let li = event.target.parentNode;
            let ul = li.parentNode;
            ul.removeChild(li);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
/* Google fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:300,400,700');

/* Root */
:root {
    --color-white:           #fff;
    --color-black:           #2D3142;
    --color-black-2:         #0E1116;
    --color-gray:            #CEE5F2;
    --color-gray-2:          #ACCBE1;
    --color-gray-3:          #CEE5F2;
    --color-green:           #439775;
    --color-blue:           #4686CC;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

}
h2 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
h3 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

button {
    background: var(--color-blue);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: var(--color-white);
}

[draggable] {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-drag: element;
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
}

ul.list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.list  button {
    background: var(--color-black);
}

.list--item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: auto;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: move;
    background: var(--color-gray);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.list--item.draggingElement {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.list--item.over {
    border-top: 3px solid var(--color-green);
}

button.remove {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
}

input#id {
    margin: auto 5px auto 0;
}

.button-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.button-wrapper .addItemInput { 
    width: 63%;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
 }
.button-wrapper .addItemButton { 
    width: 35%;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
 }
.button-wrapper .generateCode { 
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--color-green);
    margin-top: 5px;
 }


.code p {
    background: var(--color-gray); padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-gray-2);
    min-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
  <ul class="list">
    <li><span>Header</span></li>
    <li><span>Hero</span></li>
    <li><span>Intro</span></li>
    <li><span>Footer</span></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="addItemInput" placeholder="Item description">
    <button class="addItemButton">Add item</button>
    <button class="generateCode">Generate code</button>
  </div>

  <div class="code">
    <h2>Code</h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: what does this have to do with **string** length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two variants of `NodeList`, live and non-live ones. `querySelectorAll` returns a static `NodeList` that is not live. `.children` returns a live one (technically it returns an `HTMLCollection` but you can ignore this distinction for now).

To make `listCopy` be live as well,  you could use `listUl.getElementsByTagName('span')`…

To select elements by their classes, use `getElementsByClassName`. There is no way (that I know of) to get a live collection with CSS or XPath (i.e. more complex) queries, though.

Comment: @Bravo I think this comment belongs on the question, not my answer…

Comment: you are correct - sorry (don't know how that happened)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `const listCopy = listUl.querySelectorAll('span');` is initiated with the span array from the beginning.

In order to get updated list
`const listCopy = listUl.querySelectorAll('span');` will be `let listCopy = listUl.querySelectorAll('span');` and in your function

```
//Cloning code if there are checked items
copyText.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // add the following line - in this way you will select the span from the updated list
  listCopy = listUl.querySelectorAll('span');
  let copyTextFromList = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < listCopy.length; i += 1) {
    if (listCopy[i].parentNode.querySelector("input:checked")) {
      copyTextFromList += listCopy[i].textContent + ',';
    }
  }
  clonedCode.innerHTML = copyTextFromList;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use querySelectorAll, this maybe help. with this every time you check the length it recalculates and returns the value. Symbol.iterator helps you to manipulate for...of loops.

```js
const addItemInput = document.querySelector('.addItemInput');
const addItemButton = document.querySelector('.addItemButton');
const copyText = document.querySelector('.generateCode');
const listUl = document.querySelector('.list');
const list = listUl.children;
const listCopy = {
    get length() {
        return listUl.querySelectorAll('span').length
    },
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        let i = 0;
        const l = listUl.querySelectorAll('span');
        while( i < l.length ) {
            yield l[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
};
const clonedCode = document.querySelector('.code p');

//FUNCTION: Generate value/items = Draggable, Checkbox, Remove button
const attachItemListButton = (item) => {

    //Draggable
    item.draggable = "true";
    item.classList.add("list--item");

    //Checkbox
    let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.className = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.name = "chkboxName1";
    checkbox.value = "value";
    checkbox.id = "id";
    item.insertBefore(checkbox, item.childNodes[0] || null);

    //Remove button
    let remove = document.createElement('button');
    remove.className = 'remove';
    remove.textContent = 'x';
    item.appendChild(remove);
};
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    attachItemListButton(list[i]);
}


//Cloning code if there are checked items
copyText.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let copyTextFromList = "";
  for (let item of listCopy) {
    if (item.parentNode.querySelector("input:checked")) {
      copyTextFromList += item.textContent + ',';
    }
  }
  clonedCode.innerHTML = copyTextFromList;
});


//Add item from the input field to the list
addItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = addItemInput.value;
  listUl.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(span);
  attachItemListButton(li);
  addItemInput.value = '';
});


//FUNCTION: Remove button
listUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
        if (event.target.className == 'remove') {
            let li = event.target.parentNode;
            let ul = li.parentNode;
            ul.removeChild(li);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
/* Google fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:300,400,700');

/* Root */
:root {
    --color-white:           #fff;
    --color-black:           #2D3142;
    --color-black-2:         #0E1116;
    --color-gray:            #CEE5F2;
    --color-gray-2:          #ACCBE1;
    --color-gray-3:          #CEE5F2;
    --color-green:           #439775;
    --color-blue:           #4686CC;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

}
h2 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
h3 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

button {
    background: var(--color-blue);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: var(--color-white);
}

[draggable] {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-drag: element;
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
}

ul.list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.list  button {
    background: var(--color-black);
}

.list--item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: auto;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: move;
    background: var(--color-gray);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.list--item.draggingElement {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.list--item.over {
    border-top: 3px solid var(--color-green);
}

button.remove {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
}

input#id {
    margin: auto 5px auto 0;
}

.button-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.button-wrapper .addItemInput { 
    width: 63%;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
 }
.button-wrapper .addItemButton { 
    width: 35%;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
 }
.button-wrapper .generateCode { 
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--color-green);
    margin-top: 5px;
 }


.code p {
    background: var(--color-gray); padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-gray-2);
    min-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
  <ul class="list">
    <li><span>Header</span></li>
    <li><span>Hero</span></li>
    <li><span>Intro</span></li>
    <li><span>Footer</span></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="addItemInput" placeholder="Item description">
    <button class="addItemButton">Add item</button>
    <button class="generateCode">Generate code</button>
  </div>

  <div class="code">
    <h2>Code</h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
```